# netcdf configure/compilation : curl error but it's installed

Tags: curl, configure, netcdf

I must compile the netcdf package for C ([here the file](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/ftp/netcdf-c-4.7.1.tar.gz)).

When I use configure, there's an error about Curl. But Curl is effectively installed :

```
$ sudo apt show curl
Package: curl
Version: 7.38.0-4+deb8u16
Installed-Size: 334 kB
Maintainer: Alessandro Ghedini <ghedo@debian.org>
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libcurl3 (= 7.38.0-4+deb8u16), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Homepage: http://curl.haxx.se
Section: web
Priority: optional
Download-Size: 202 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Here the error when I compile :

```
$ ./configure
configure: netCDF 4.7.1
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: checking user options
checking whether a NCIO_MINBLOCKSIZE was specified... 256
checking for valgrind... no
checking if fsync support is enabled... no
checking if jna bug workaround is enabled... no
checking whether we should build netCDF-4... yes
checking whether we should build with HDF5... yes
checking do we require hdf5 dynamic-loading support... yes
checking whether reading of HDF4 SD files is to be enabled... no
checking whether to fetch some sample HDF4 files from Unidata ftp site to test HDF4 reading (requires wget)... no
checking whether we should attempt to install netcdf-fortran (EXPERIMENTAL)... no
checking whether parallel IO tests should be run... no
checking whether a user specified program to run mpi programs... mpiexec
checking whether a default chunk size in bytes was specified... 4194304
checking whether a maximum per-variable cache size for HDF5 was specified... 67108864
checking whether a number of chunks for the default per-variable cache was specified... 10
checking whether a default file cache size for HDF5 was specified... 4194304
checking whether a default file cache maximum number of elements for HDF5 was specified... 1009
checking whether a default cache preemption for HDF5 was specified... 0.75
checking whether netCDF-4 logging is enabled... no
checking whether nc_set_log_level() function is included (will do nothing unless enable-logging is also used)... yes
checking whether DAP client(s) are to be built... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for curl_easy_setopt in -lcurl... no
checking for library containing curl_easy_setopt... no
configure: error: curl required for remote access. Install curl or build with --disable-dap.
```

And this is [the link to visualize the config.log](https://framabin.org/p/?d85ef3f7def70ca9#57SAcY4yIHwU2rMDBl8Fr3khijczf+b6uf+bMSfmRoY=) (configure verbose).

Comment: "libcurl3-gnutls" and "libcurl3" is also, already installed (Linux jessie 3.16.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.74-1 (2019-09-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: I've re-install "curl", but there's a warning : "WARNING: curl and libcurl versions do not match. Functionality may be affected. curl: symbol lookup error: curl: undefined symbol: curl_mime_free". :(